# Navegação entre Páginas

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xaml, cross-platform

Estou fazendo um app de pedidos de venda com o **Xamarin**, mas estou com um problema, em chama ruma pagina de pesquisa, e retornar o valor selecionado para a página que eu estava. Vou explicar melhor abaixo.

Tela 1:

- Tela de cadastro do pedido, nessa tela, o operador digita o código do cliente, ou clica em uma "lupinha" para abrir a tela de listagem de clientes, estou utilizando Navigation.PushAsync(telaPesquisa); pra chamar a tela de listagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela 2:

- Tela de listagem de clientes, essa tela exibe os clientes cadastrados, e ao selecionar um cliente, e apertar OK, teria que retornar para a "Tela 1", mas está não esta retornando. Eu estou utilizando Navigation.PopAsync();

Alguem poderia me dizer em como fazer isso? Basicamente, é abrir uma tela de pesquisa, selecionar o cliente, e retornar pra tela atual.

Att.
Felipe

Comment: Seria bom colocar o código referente a `Navigation.PushAsync(telaPesquisa)`

Comment: Só tinha isso mesmo no código, por isso não coloquei.
Consegui ajustar aqui, foi erro meu mesmo, o evento do botão estava "bindado" duas vezes, no código C# e no código XAML.

Por isso que o PopAsync não funcionada, estava voltando 2 paginas. Agora está correto.

Agradeço a ajuda @rubStackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

A navegação no Xamarin utilizando a instância do INavigationService utiliza um esquema de pilhas para realizar a navegação. O INavigationService possui duas pilhas que guardam as páginas navegadas: uma para páginas e outra para modal. Quando utilizamos o PushAsync inserimos uma página na pilha de páginas. Quando utilizamos o PushModalAsync inserimos uma página na pilha de modais e essa página sera tratada como modal..

A função do PopAsync é utilizada para remover o último item que foi inserido na pilha de modais.

Dessa forma quando você usa o PushAsync e em seguida o PopAsync nada ocorre porque a pilha que foi utilizada foi a de páginas e não existe nenhuma modal.

A correção para seu problema seria usar o PushModalAsync ao invés do PushAsync .