# Como recuperar uma string de outra pagina no Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Ja vi varios exemplos de como abrir uma pag enviando uma string pra ela mas eu queria um exemplo de como fazer o contrario, abrir uma pagina e ela retornar uma string quando for fechada.

A minha siuação é mais ou menos essa [Navegação entre Páginas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135084/navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-p%C3%A1ginas)

Só que o cara resolveu e não ficou claro como fazer isso e o post tem 2 anos.

Eu tenho duas paginas:
**MainPage.cs** e **PaginaPesquisa.cs**

Quero que a partir do **MainPage.cs** abrir **PaginaPesquisa.cs** e o **PaginaPesquisa.cs** retornar uma string pra eu usar na **MainPage.cs.**

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho vivamente a usar [Prism](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Getting-Started.html), facilita problemas de navegação como o descrito aqui, e a usar o modelo **MVVM**(Model View ViewModel), para distribuir e estabelecer melhor as responsabilidades numa aplicação mobile.

Deixo aqui um breve resumo de como funciona a **Navegação no Prism** antes de passar para a solução:

> **EN:** Navigating in a Prism application is conceptually different than standard navigation in Xamarin.Forms. While Xamarin.Forms navigation relies on a Page class instance to navigate, Prism removes all dependencies on Page types to achieve loosely coupled navigation from within a ViewModel. In Prism, the concept of navigating to a View or navigating to a ViewModel does not exist. Instead, you simply navigate to an experience, or a unique identifier, which represents the target view you wish to navigate to in your application.
>
> **PT:** Navegar em uma aplicação Prism é conceitualmente diferente da navegação padrão em Xamarin.Forms. Embora a navegação Xamarin.Forms dependa de uma instância da classe Page para navegar, o Prism remove todas as dependências dos tipos de página para obter uma navegação acoplada a partir de um ViewModel. No Prism, o conceito de navegar para um View ou navegar para um ViewModel não existe. Em vez disso, basta navegar para uma experiência ou um identificador exclusivo, que representa a vista de destino para a qual você deseja navegar na aplicação.

Agora para a **Solução:**

1º - Fazer com que os ViewModels extendam do **ViewModelBase** (gerado pelo Prism na criação de um projeto), para ter acesso ás interface de navegação no construtor e guardar-la.

```
public class MainPage: ViewModelBase
{
    INavigationService _navigationService;
    public MainPage(INavigationService navigationService): base(navigationService)
    {
       _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
}
```

2º - Fazer override nos métodos **OnNavigatedTo** e **OnNavigatedFrom**, para quando navegas *para* uma página, e para quando navegas *de uma* página respetivamente

**PesquisaPageViewModel.cs**

```
    public override void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(parameters);
    }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
    }
```

3º - A Navegação para as páginas é feita da seguinte maneira:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("PesquisaPage");//O identificador é o nome do ficheiro da view, (Por convenção, em Prism, o *naming* das páginas termina sempre em "Page")
```

4º - imaginemos que queremos passar uma string da **PesquisaPageViewModel** para a **MainPageViewModel**, como queremos passar para a página anterior (o equivalente a popasync), fazemos no **OnNavigatedFrom**:

```
    public override void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        string nome = "Ricardo"
        parameters.Add("KeyDoObjeto", nome);//Add(Key, Obj)
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(parameters);
    }
```

5º - Por fim, na **MainPageViewModel** obtemos a string no **OnNavigatedTo**

```
    public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
        string nomeVindoDaPesquisaPage = (string)parameters["KeyDoObjeto"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue fazer isso facilmente utilizando [MessagingCenter](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center), onde basicamente sua função é realizar a comunicação entre objetos, que no seu caso são páginas diferentes.

Para isso basta configurar a aplicação  para ouvir uma dada mensagem, no ex, abaixo "Hi"

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(Application.Current, "Hi", (sender, message) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
    Console.WriteLine(message);
});
```

E depois no outro objeto, realizar o envio da mensagem, conforme ex. abaixo:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(Application.Current, "Hi", "Minha saudação vinda de outra página");
```

Ao final, quando a página for removida(fechada), não se esqueça de cancelar a assinatura:

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string> (Application.Current, "Hi");
```